# why are osx `say` command voices worse in a newer macbook pro?

Tags: macos, terminal, text-to-speech-voices

My older macbook pro, bought in 2015, has Mojave 10.14.6. The following command
`say -v anna uh`
sounds like a German speaker saying the long letter "u", like an American would say "ooooo!" to express surprise or to say that a bite of food tastes particularly good. 
But on the 13-inch MacBook Pro, Catalina 10.15.4, that I purchased on 20 March 2020, the same command yields a noise that does not sound human at all. Ting-ting, the mainland Chinese voice, still pronounces the syllable the same as before; so does Mei-Jia. Amelie, the French-Canadian, used to pronounce it in a beautiful way, very French (and still does so on my older macbook pro) but the command `say -v Amelie uh` on the new computer yields no sound at all.

What in the world caused this and is there a way to restore the better pronunciation?

Comment: I'm a native English speaker & I would have no real idea how you would expect the word `uh` to be pronounced, other than as some kind of verbal filler when you're not, uh, sure what the rest of your sentence is going to be.

Comment: A lot of the high quality voices are over a gigabyte each as I recall, so they are not preinstalled. You have to go into the text-to-speech settings and tell it to download the high quality versions of the voices you use. Maybe that's been done on your older machine, but you haven't done it on your new machine yet.

Comment: @Tetsujin, my motivation is that I am interested in accents and in particular enjoy observing the differences in how the voices pronounce `uh`. My mother tongue is American (Massachusetts / Oregon). When Samantha (American) says `uh`, it sounds familiar to me. It is a long drawn-out syllable, as though she means "Oh, I see." For Tessa (South Africa) and Fiona (Scotland), it sounds more like a hiccup. And Amelie (Québéquoise) pronounces in a distinctively French way, uttering a phoneme that is not part of any English-language accents I know, with the possible exception of Wisconsin / Oshkosh.

Comment: If you want to hear the variants on `uh`.. which still isn't a word, then why not try words that end in an `uh` or `ə` sound to find which ones are going to pronounce it ohh. Try Scarborough or thorough, both of which end in ə in British English, but usually in ohh, or ow in American.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Spiff that was the answer. On macos Mojave 10.14.6, Preferences, Accessibility. Left side of the window, click on Speech. Right side, there is a field for System Voice. Click on that and then at the bottom of the pulldown menu click on Customize. Then you see a list of voices, sorted under language and Female / Male. Some are already checked, some not. Checking voices that are not yet checked and not yet working on this computer, brought up a notice or warning that this would entail downloading a lot of bytes. American voice `Vicki` was only 35 MB, however.

For some reason, some voices that are already available on this computer are nevertheless not checked.